# Notification not working from Android broadcast receiver

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to notify the user when my app makes it's daily check.  The code runs fine but the notification never appears in the status bar.  Can anyone see why?

```
public class OnNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    WakeReminderIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    context.startService(i);

    Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
    int icon = extra.getInt("icon");
    notification(context, icon);

    Log.d("DailyCheck", "Checking for sales");
}
 private void notification(Context ctx, int icon) {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);


        CharSequence tickerText = "ticker";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;


        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);


        CharSequence contentTitle = "Title Here";
        CharSequence contentText = "Text here";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        mNotificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
    }
```

}

EDIT:  I tried copying it into my main thread (the notification method) and it worked fine.  So it has to be something with BroadcastReceiver?

EDIT 2:  Context being passed into it is MainActivity.this (my primary activity)

Answer (score 0):

Try this line at the top of notification and then use this context for the rest of the method:

```
Context context = ctx.getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: Not sure what this would accomplish...but I tried it anyways and it didn't work.